# Sqlinjection in where Clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I am testing an application and encountered a bit unique issue I have found that application is sending parameters like

?$filter=ModuleName+ne+'Bookings'+and+ModuleName+eq+'Transport'+and+(ContactID+eq+null+and+IsToBeShown+eq+true)+&$orderby=ReportName

Obviously I can add and +1+eq+1 and all results are shown but if I try to terminate the query like using (;, or ') it gives me error.

Kind of not sure how to terminate the query and add a union etc. clause to extract data .

Any thoughts are welcome

Answer (score 0):

It seams that `$filter` is used in where clause and probably is added to some other hard coded conditions. To get all the result you need to add `or 1 eq 1` (or instead of and).

It may make a difference if other condidions are added before or after `$filter`.

Try `$filter=union all select ... where 1 eq 1` but remember that column list must be the same in all unioned queries. You don't need to terminate the query with `;`

Replace spaces with +, I wrote spaces to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the first thing in my mind. but the issue is : without invoking error I dont know the name of Columns or table . As the error generated is like:  $filter=union+all+selecti+1+from+users result s is like: Syntax error at position 9 in 'union all selecti 1 from users'.</m:message><m:innererror><m:message>Syntax error at position 9 in 'union all selecti 1 from users'.</m:message><m:type>Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException

Comment: So effectively I dont know the name of tables or columns

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sys.tables` to get table names, then `SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'`

Comment: Syntax error at position 11 in 'SELECT name FROM sys.tables'.</m:message><m:type>Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException</m:type><m:stacktrace>   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ExpressionLexer.ValidateToken(ExpressionTokenKind t)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.UriQueryExpressionParser.ParseFilter(String filter)&#xD;
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.Parsing.RequestExpressionParser.ParseFilter()

Comment: Similar error for Select *  or even Select 1.  So in the $filter only filter clause is acceptable.  Thought interestingly error is not on select but the name of the column